# Show different categories on different pages?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site for clothing, I have 3 pages:

Men
Women
Kids

In each page I want to show a list of categories on the sidebar, at the moment all these categories appear on each page, how can I assign different categories to each page so that only relevant categories appear?

Thanks!

Comment: Search wordpress.org extentions for something like "custom category list" - for example first thing that comes up is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-categories-list/ - widget that allows include/exclude categories for display, use of short-code, so you can create wordpress pages with customizable list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates or a plugin semilar to Ultimate Category Excluder ..

Goodluck